# VB.NET Project on rollout .dll should autoregister

Tags: vb.net, dll

net** Problem,

I made a Project and added one .DLL. If I start the Project on other PC (Rollout) the DLL should autoregister i don't want to do a batch DAT for this, maybe one data in the Project or something like this. I really don't know what I should do, maybe I can also eddied the DLL DAT I hope u can help me :)

It's an estos DLL “NETTSCLib.dll”